# Why Server header in not getting removed from the response in 500 error?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, header, http-headers, iis-7.5

I recently scanned my application for the vulnerability, got minor fixes but for one of them I tried hard still not able to fix. For some operation my site throws 500  error and when I check header of that error, it is having server header named IIS 7.5. I have already used URL rewrite rule,registry fix,URL scan thing, but seems to be nothing is working.How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `Server` HTTP header, which will probably be set to something along the lines of `Microsoft-IIS/7.5` then the easiest way is to overwrite it with a blank or custom value in IIS. You can remove it completely by creating your own HTTP module. The following link discusses the manifold methods you can try:

http://www.dionach.com/blog/easily-remove-unwanted-http-headers-in-iis-70-to-85